# Gilgule Hasgacha in mi Yodeya

Tags: discussion

I am experiencing a strange and wonderful feeling (not a delusional perception).

1. First I read a question on Yibbum [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53019/9215) that leads me to a Gemara on Yebamot 103a about Chalitsa for a man without legs.
2. After this I soon see a question about kings [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71545/9215) that leads to a Mishna in Sanhedrin 19b and gives me a part of the answer for the former question,
3. and finally a question on Yehareg Veal Yaavor [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71721/9215), and thanks to the Gemara pf the first question I find in Yebamot 103a the answer to this question

There is a snow ball effect. דברי תורה עניים במקום אחד ועשירים במקום אחרת 
I am interesting to know if and how other people are experiencing similar pleasure in mi yodeya Q&A.